# itext7 with pdfocr in .net core application. compatibility problem

Tags: c#, pdf, .net-core, ocr, itext7

I need to read PDF image in .net core 6 application. i am trying it with itext7 and pdfocr

but i am getting error
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning NU1701  Package 'itext.pdfocr.api 3.0.1' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1' instead of the project target framework 'net6.0-windows7.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

```
 string pdfPath = "path/to/your/pdf/document.pdf";
        int pageNumber = 1; // Replace with the page number containing the image

        try
        {
            PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(pdfPath));
            PdfOcrTextExtractionStrategy strategy = new PdfOcrTextExtractionStrategy();
            
            // Language and other configuration for OCR
            PdfOcrPdfDocument pdfOcrDocument = new PdfOcrPdfDocument(pdfDocument, new DefaultPdfOcrEngine(), new PdfOcrTesseract4Configuration());
            
            // Extract text from the specified page
            ITextExtractionStrategy extractionStrategy = new FilteredTextEventListener(new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(), new TextRegionEventFilter(pageNumber));
            String extractedText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfOcrDocument, pageNumber, extractionStrategy);
            
            Console.WriteLine("Extracted Text:");
            Console.WriteLine(extractedText);
            
            pdfDocument.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + ex.Message);
        }
```

code i wanted to try is